# Linear System where Coefficient Matrix is a Kronecker Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products, tensors

I have a system of linear equations where the coefficient matrix and right hand side is given by a Kronecker product:

$(A_1 \otimes A_2) u = f_1 \otimes f_2$

My question:  Is the solution simply given by $u = u_1 \otimes u_2$ where $u_1, u_2$ are solutions of $A_1 u_1 = f_1$ and $A_2 u_2 = f_2$ respectively?

Edit: My assumption is obviously based on the assumption that $(A_1 \otimes A_2)(u_1 \otimes u_2) = (A_1 u_1) \otimes (A_2 u_2)$ holds.  Maybe I have a mental block, but I wonder why I can't find any reference to such a trivial fact (this in turn makes me suspicious that I am missing something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually that simple: YES the solution is given by by $u=u_1 \otimes u_2$ where $u_1,u_2$ are solutions of $A_1 u_1=f_1$ and $A_2 u_2=f_2$ respectively